# c# - How can i convert bytes to shorts

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, file, freeze

I am trying to convert a byte array to a array to shorts but it doesn't seem to work. The issue is, my for loop will stop when it gets to the bitconverter. Here is my code snippet:

```
byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes("frame.jpg");
short[] output = new short[input.Length / 2];
Console.WriteLine("Converting bytes to shorts");
for (int i = 0; i == input.Length; i++)
{
    output[i/2] = BitConverter.ToInt16(input, i);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(output[i/2]) + " ");
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: I don't think `i == input.Length` will work. Don't you want `i < input.Length - 1` and `i = i + 1`? I don't believe for one second that your code will "stop" when it gets to the BitConverter line. Error maybe, but not stop.

Comment: The title made me think you were looking for a programming gig in a sunny venue, somehow...

Comment: to read image data check [`Image.FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.7.2). To read shorts from a file, check [`BinaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I posted a hasty answer and deleted it, because well in all honesty the question could be a lot better... With some deduction I have come to the conclusion that what you actually want to do is load a bunch of bytes into their word representation. Meaning shift the first byte left by 8 bits and add the second byte.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("frame.jpg");
var output = new List<ushort>();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
{
    try
    {
        output.Add((ushort)((bytes[i] * 256) + bytes[i + 1]));
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        output.Add((ushort)(bytes[i] * 256));
    }
}
return output.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't far off, just a few logic errors in the `for` loop:

```
public static void Main()
{
        byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes("frame.jpg");
        short[] output = new short[input.Length / 2];
        Console.WriteLine("Converting bytes to shorts");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length-1; i+=2)
        {
            output[i/2] = BitConverter.ToInt16(input, i);
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(output[i/2]) + " ");
        }   
}
```

You should also probably check that the input image has an even number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You used `ToInt16(input, i)` in your code.
So I think this was wrong.
I suggest you to use `BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)input[i] , (byte)input[i+1] },i)` to fix your issues.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint16?view=netframework-4.7.2